# How to query from XML with SchemaVersion?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii" ?> 
<LoanSetupFile SchemaVersion="3.0" NumberOfLoans="2" xmlns="https://www.something.com/schemas">
 <Loan ServicerLoanNumber="1"/>
 <Loan ServicerLoanNumber="2"/>
</LoanSetupFile>
```

I'm trying to get the ServicerLoanNumber attribute. I've tried a lot of ways, and this might be my closest attempt, but still it's returning null

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("fileName.xml");
XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace(); //This gives me the correct namespace
var loans = from l in doc.Descendants(ns+"Loan") select new { ServicerLoanNumber = l.Attribute("ServicerLoanNumber").Value };
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with this? Do I need to include the SchemaVersion? If so, how?

Thanks a lot..

Comment: Have you tried making use of the overload for `doc.Descendants()` that takes an `XName`?

Comment: I believe that's the one I'm using. The other overload takes no parameter.

Comment: I suppose more specifically what I meant, have you tried actually making use of the `XName` type? I see you're doing string concatenation now, but changing that to `ns.GetName("Loan")` (I think, it's been a while but it's something like that) should work.

Comment: I think the method implicitly converts the string into XName because it's not complaining about type.. I might be wrong though

Comment: It does, but my guess is that `ns+"Loan"` is evaluating to `"https://www.something.com/schemasLoan"`, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a quick test of your code in a winform, it is working fine.

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""us-ascii"" ?>");
        sb.Append(@"<LoanSetupFile SchemaVersion=""3.0"" NumberOfLoans=""2"" xmlns=""https://www.something.com/schemas"">");
        sb.Append(@"<Loan ServicerLoanNumber=""1""/>");
        sb.Append(@"<Loan ServicerLoanNumber=""2""/>");
        sb.Append(@"</LoanSetupFile>");

        var doc = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString() ?? "")));
        XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace(); //This gives me the correct namespace
        var loans = from l in doc.Descendants(ns + "Loan") 
                    select new { ServicerLoanNumber = l.Attribute("ServicerLoanNumber").Value };

        // Temporarily display the values
        foreach (var l in loans)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(l.ServicerLoanNumber);
        }
```

Comment: I tried putting your code into a different program, and it doesn't like this line var doc = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString() ?? ""))) because there's no overload that takes that type of parameter. I have included System.IO. Any idea?

Comment: I hope you included the System.IO assembly      "using System.IO;"

Comment: Ok, after running my code again, it's working somehow. This is beyond my comprehension. But thanks, Consult Yarla for pointing it out to me :)